# Can any resource be revoked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

### Simple question:

Can any URL be revoked (using [`URL.revokeObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL))?

Let's say I load a stylesheet using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` in HTML

Just for fun and giggles, could I then at anytime revoke "theme.css" using `window.URL.revokeObjectURL( "theme.css" )` or something like that?

#### A little bit of background:

I have used the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for loading local resources (gathered from an HTML file-input) into the blob, but I have not used it a lot for resources loaded from an external source (loaded from a domain/website), primarily because I have never needed to; if I need to get an image, I would just create an image object, and assign the URL to the source attribute *as a string* (not an Object URL), then delete that image later if required.

However, I got curious. Hence, my question.

Answer (score 0):

But you have no reference to this linked css file... So, in short, you can't. This method releases and assign for garbage collector, only resources that was previously created with createObjectURL method - objects you have reference for.

Comment: Ok, so resources for the most part are collected by the garbage collector i.e. when they are not used, they are swept away. The exception to this rule is Object URLs, correct?